# How's Helmholtz correct that "Whoever in the pursuit of science, seeks after immediate practical utility may rest assured that he seeks in vain"?

Tags: quote

I first saw this quote at the top of p. 186, [*Phonetics For Dummies* (2013 1 ed)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118505085).
A secondary source: [*The Many Faces Of Science* (2000)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0813365511). But I don't know [the page number](https://books.google.com/books?id=b1JPDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT41&ots=wO9S9vtxGI&dq=%22whoever%20in%20the%20pursuit%20of%20science%2C%20seeks%22&pg=PT42#v=onepage&q=%22whoever%20in%20the%20pursuit%20of%20science,%20seeks%22&f=false).

> 2: According to the classic ideal, the only value recognized by the scientist as such, 
>   the only value actually involved in doing science, is that of knowledge for its own 
>   sake. She may welcome the possibility of useful applications of her research, but as a 
>   scientist she is devoted purely and simply to the extension of human knowledge as 
>   an end in itself. In this respect, she is just like her university colleagues the Sanskrit 
>   philologist, the medieval historian, and the pure mathematician, who delight in the 
>   achievement of new knowledge and understanding even if there is no prospect of its 
>   being useful in any practical way As an eloquent nineteenth-century expression of 
>   this view, consider this passage from the physicist Hermann von Helmboltz:
>
> > **Whoever, in the pursuit of science, seeks after immediate practical utility, may generally rest 
> >     assured that he will seek in vain.** All that science can achieve is a perfect knowledge and a 
> >     perfect understanding of the action of natural and moral forces. Each individual student must 
> >     be content to find his reward in rejoicing over new discoveries, as over new victories of mind 
> >     over reluctant matter, or in enjoying the aesthetic beauty of a well-ordered field of 
> >     knowledge, where the connection and filiation of every detail is clear to the mind, he must 
> >     rest satisfied with the consciousness that he too has contributed something to the increasing 
> >     fund of knowledge on which the dominion of man over all the forces hostile to intelligence 
> >     reposes. 
> >     (Helmholtz 1893, quoted in Ravetz 1971, 39)

The emboldened feels false for applied sciences, like biology, [neuroscience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_neuroscience) or medicine? These unsolved problems do seek answers of "immediate practical utility"?

Comment: A quote of a secondary source of a quote of [Hermann von Helmholtz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_von_Helmholtz) ? This has nothing to do with History of science.

Comment: Having said thta, he was a great scientist and experimentator, and a philosophical materialist. But he was clearly a proponent of the idea that *knowledge* is the basic value of science.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA [“Wer bei der Verfolgung der Wissenschaften nach unmittelbarem praktischen Nutzen jagt, kann ziemlich sicher sein, dass er vergebens jagen wird.”](//archive.org/stream/bub_gb_v1zCFTg9eLMC#page/n33) The history of such quotes could still be interesting. Recently popular: [“Chacun sait que l'électricité n'a pas été inventée en cherchant à perfectionner les bougies”](//books.google.com/books?id=-pIrXWhipqUC&ots=Pa0-cHskGC&pg=PA18&dq=%22Chacun+sait+que+l'électricité+n'a+pas+été+inventée+en+cherchant+à+perfectionner+les+bougies%22) ([2004](//www.worldcat.org/oclc/55678403)).

Comment: Even in biology, neuroscience or medicine looking for "immediate practical utility" without fundamental research would be short-sighted and counterproductive. As history amply shows, many discoveries of practical utility are only made possible by decades (or centuries) of exploration "for the sake of knowledge". In neuroscience, for example, many researchers are currently preoccupied with questions about free will and consciousness that have no obvious "practical utility", but one day the answers might.

Answer (score 1):

That's history: the current (neoliberal) Ideology insists that everything is done for  profit and of course it claims that this has always been  true. Within its limits  one would start  wondering how could people think that a rational action would aim at anything that does not bring immediate benefit. The ["One dimensional Man"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-Dimensional_Man) was recognized  already in the sixties.

Comment: ... and people should, but may not, realize that "neo-liberal" has a meaning very different (opposite?) from what "liberal" would mean in contemporary U.S., for example. In terms of popular political parlance in the U.S., "neoliberal" would be more like (though differing in some regards) "conservative" or even "libertarian".

Comment: But "profit" is subjective. Somebody will feel fulfilled by getting to know, others by money.